# What is the best way to post from Angular 8 to Node.JS

Tags: node.js, angular

I have this function in my service in angular.
till now i use GET methods and now i need to post some data to the server.

This is a GET request:

```
getReports(userID) {
    return this.http.request<Reports[]>('GET', this.baseUrl + this.REPORTS_API + '/' +
     this.USER_API + '/' + userID, { responseType: 'json' });
}
```

And now i need to post a data

```
createNewReport(companyID, type, year){
    return this.http.request<[]>('POST', this.baseUrl + this.REPORTS_API, { responseType: 'json'});
}
```

Where should i put the data ??

Comment: No shortage of [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the data as,

```
createNewReport(companyID, type, year){
    const data = JSON.stringify({companyId: companyID, type: type});
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.REPORTS_API, data , { responseType: 'json'});
};
```